# Readinga file in java

Tags: java, file, io

what i was trying to do was copying a content of file using File using File input stream and writing it in to another file

```
 InputStream is = null;
        FileOutputStream fos=null;
        try{
            is = new FileInputStream("D:\\helloworld.txt");
             fos = new FileOutputStream("D:\\helloworld1.txt");
            byte[] buffer = new byte[255];
            while(is.read(buffer)>-1){

               fos.write(is.read(buffer,0,buffer.length));
            }
            is.close();
           fos.close();
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
    }
```

**content of helloworld:**

```
vsdaewfscvadfdsohcdvwbuivbASJXBBfjbzx cidbv k ab SifvicvahisvcbxsiSDobhsxcb Z asvfuigevwifuvweivfb
```

**output of helloworld is:**

```
ÿ
```

Comment: It is a good thing to practice file handling manually. Needless to say that in a real application, you would rather use :  `Files.copy(Paths.get("D:\\helloworld.txt"), Paths.get("D:\\helloworld1.txt"));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 int r=0;
 while((r=is.read(buffer))>-1){
      fos.write(buffer,0,r);
 }
```

You're reading into buffer twice and writing the number of bytes read...